# If Statement with multiple conditions on one column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to create an if statement where I can get a value in my new cell if the values or strings in one column are either 0-1,000 or 1001-5,00, then 2, if they are only 5,001-10,00 then I get 4 and if it is 10,000+ then I get 4.?

SO far I only have something like `=IF($U502="10,000+",5,0) and =IF($U502="5,001-10,00",1,0)`

where i get 5 if it is 10,000+ and 1 if it is 5,001-10,000

I want to combine them both into one formula and also add that if the value is also either 0-1,000 or 1001-5,000 then 2

The values in column are not numbers they are ranges already defined

The column values are like below,

```
Column
0-1,000
1,001-5,000
5,001-10,000
10,000+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an expression like that:

```
=if(or($U502="0-1,000",$U502="1,000-5,000"),2,if($U502="5,001-10,000",4,5))
```

Feel free to change the ranges or the resulting values per range if this does not suit your needs.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear in my question I added more info, @Marios

Comment: @Chris90 the first and last sentence of your question does not line up. Check values and ranges in your description.

Comment: Can you check now @Marios